# How will you retrieve Value object if two Keys will have same hashcode?

Tags: java

How will you retrieve Value object  if two Keys will have same hashcode?

Comment: Suppose we were to assume a hashmap made using an array of linked lists when two different keys are hashed and produce the same hashcode. They will be stored in the same array index (due to the same hashcode). However, due to hashcode collision, they will be populated in different linked list nodes. 

So when retrieving using a key, it will hash the key and using hashcode go directly to that array index O(1) but will have to iterate through the linked list looking for that key O(n).

Hence if the hashcode function is bad, you will have all data stored in the same array index.

Answer (score 1):

When two keys have the same hash code, the `equals` function will be called to decide what to do:

- If the keys have identical hash codes and are equal to each other (based on the result of the call to `equals`) the two keys are considered identical, so only one key would be in the hash map
- If the keys have identical hash codes, but are not equal, then both keys would be present in the hash table.

Answer (score 0):

**Hash Map Internals**

There is an `Entry[]` array called table which has size `16`.
This table stores `Entry` class’s object. `HashMap` class has a inner class called `Entry`.This Entry have key value as instance variable.

Lets see structure of entry class Entry Structure.

```
static class Entry implements Map.Entry
{
        final K key;
        V value;
        Entry next;
        final int hash;
        ...//More code goes here
}
```

Whenever we try to put any key value pair in `hashmap`, `Entry` class object is instantiated for key value and that object will be stored in above mentioned `Entry[]`(table).

Now you must be wondering, where will above created `Enrty` object get stored(exact position in table). The answer  is, hash code is calculated for a key by calling `hascode()` method. **This hashcode is used to calculate index for above `Entry[]` table.**

If hash code is same then index is same, in this way it overrides your last value.

Example :

```
Hashcode for Japan = 95 as its length is odd.
Hashcode for India =95 as its length is odd
HashCode for Russia=31 as its length is even.
HashCode for France=31 as its length is even.
```

We have put 4 key-values in hashmap but it seems to have only 2!!!!This is **because if two objects have same hashcode**, they will be stored at same index. Now question arises how? It stores objects in a form of `LinkedList(logically)`. [Refer very good tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

If **`Two Key are same`** then JAVA will **`overwrite the previous key and value with new one`**.

Comment: Yes, but he was asking for the same hashcode, not the same key.

Answer (score 0):

If two key have the same `hashCode` (which doesn't mean they are identical), they will be stored in the same linked list inside the `HashMap` (assuming you are asking about `HashMap`s), and the value to be returned will be determined be comparing all the keys that have the same hashCode with the requested key (using `equals`).

If the two keys are the same, only one value will be stored for that single key.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "list of the HashMap".